# Phone number formatting PHP

Tags: php, web-applications, format, phone-number, prefix

With the APIs of a third part web application, I retrieve the data of the customer including email, country, phone number and so on.

Let's imagine that I have a customer that inserts in that web application a phone number **incorrectly**. I've created two types of check to correct the phone number:

```
//phone prefix totally missing
if( substr($phone_number, 0, 1) != '+' ) {
    if( substr($phone_number, 0, 2) == '00' ) {
        $phone_number = '+'.substr($phone_number, 2);
    } else {
        $phone_number = $this->params['prefix'].$phone_number;
    }
}


// double prefix prevention (since October 2019)
if (substr($phone_number, 0, 1) == '+' && substr($phone_number, 0, 3) == substr($phone_number, 3, 3)) {
    $phone_number = substr($phone_number, 3);
} else if(substr($phone_number, 0, 1) == '+' && substr($phone_number, 0, 2) == substr($phone_number, 2, 2)) {
    $phone_number = substr($phone_number, 2);
} else if(substr($phone_number, 0, 1) == '+' && substr($phone_number, 0, 4) == substr($phone_number, 4, 4)) {
    $phone_number = substr($phone_number, 4);
}
```

There's anyway a problem. Let's imagine that a customer inserts the following incorrect phone number: "39 3939xxxxxx", where the first "39" is the Italian prefix without the + that is missing (so, the phone number is not correct).

In this case, I'm totally lost, since if I remove the "39", then I would remove also half of the number; if I add instead a + to the "39"s, I risk to have something like "+39+39+39xxxxxx".

The main problem is that I don't know if the prefix is included in the number or not, so I'm stuck here, since I don't know what kind of control implement without leaving any margin of error.

EDIT: I've noticed that there's a Google library available to help with this issue, but it's a problem for me to integrate it in my web application at the moment.

Comment: Considering that the prefix is the first character couldn't you just check if it is there and if not you'll add it?

Comment: Are you comfortable with RegEx ?

Comment: @Synapsis yes I could, but what about the case of the number `39 3939xxxxxx` I've described? I would add another +39, which would generate a number of 14 cyphers including the prefix, which is incorrect.

Comment: @Cid honestly, not that much.. but what is your suggestion anyway?

Comment: That's just a thought, but if you aren't comfortable with RegEx, that will be giving you some code you can't maintain

Comment: So, if you have this number 39 3939393939 you can just check for the space.
The two parameters for the control should be the "+" or the " " (blank space).
Also you can count the lenght of the number. (I know it is variable cause some numbers have more then 10 cyphers but you could cast the number to 10/11 cyphers and check if the remaning part of the string is a prefix)For that solution you need a list of all the existing prefixes tho

Comment: Join the room to chat about that problem (in italiano magari): https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/200551/problema-numero

Comment: @Synapsis Well, the space isn't a valid check. Unfortunately, it may happen that a client inserts numbers like "1 123 456 7", or "39 0574 123456", with the space between the regional prefix and the variable number. Moreover, not all the countries have 10 cyphers: in germany, for example, the number can have from 9 to 12 (or 13) cyphers. I would say that this is it's quite a complex situation.

Comment: This question would be more clear with a [mcve]. In fact, having 5 or 10 different test strings would be very helpful.